# Source of information - command who

Tags: command, who

I would like to know how the command `"who"` pulls out information about `ssh` history into a Linux system. For example, on my shared-network workstation, where everyone can `ssh` into it:

```
[johny@gandor ~]$ who
johny :0           2018-08-30 06:44 (:0)
johny pts/0        2018-08-30 06:45 (:0.0)
johny pts/1        2018-08-30 06:45 (:0.0)
Keiven pts/2        2018-08-30 19:46 (:50.0)
seman pts/6        2018-08-31 15:15 (:50.0)
johny pts/7        2018-08-31 15:51 (:50.0)
casper pts/8        2018-08-31 16:53 (:50.0)
johny pts/10       2018-09-01 06:25 (:50.0)
```

I think that this information is, originally, stored somewhere in Linux system files and the command `"who"` reads that information from that file? if so, where is that file located?

Comment: If you run `strace who` you'll see exactly what files it's getting the information from.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you. I use Cantos 7. I don't see any path from the output of "strace". Also cd into "/var/run/utmp."  is not feasible. I mean there is no such file!

Comment: @Kasper: `/var/run/utmp` is a file, so you cannot `cd` into it. You also might want to add the output of `strace -e trace=open who` to your question.

Comment: Thank you Zeta, I am new to this forum and I am not familiar with the rules. I will re-edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for who. e.g. "If FILE is not specified, use /var/run/utmp."

This is not a text file, so opening with `vi` will offer a poor view of the file contents.  `od -c /var/run/utmp | more` would serve better.

Comment: @Kasper Adding questions to existing questions is frowned upon. A question should have _one_ acceptable answer. If someone now comes along and answers _only_ the `utmp` part, none of the answers would be complete. That's why the general rule is: one post = one question. Feel free to open another post (although I've already answered your additional question in my answer, btw).

Comment: And hence https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466257/ .

Answer (score 3):

If you run `strace -e open who`, you will see all files that `who` opens. On Linux, that includes `/var/run/utmp`. `utmp` is **not** a human-readable file, instead it is a sequence of `utmp` structures (see `utmpx(5)`). On FreeBSD, `who` opens `/var/run/utx.active`.

You can also find this information at `who --help`, `man 1 who` or even `info who`, where the default file is mentioned.

Comment: Good answer, hence +1, and generally `strace` is the way to go if you want to know what a program does underneath the hood. If there's no interesting file showing up with `open()` syscalls, that can mean it's likely is communicating with kernel via library and gets information from there.